# JSON deserialization for property starting with underscore ("_id") not working

Tags: java, json, spring

Posting the question as I can't find solution specific to below problem.

One of the 3rd part REST service we are consuming return response similar to
`{ "_id": "d55eb7c0",
   "applicationType": "TEST",
   "applicationId": "uxhJ1hcT1F8bpL3xAWvTjsymNcd1RArv",
   "description": "Some Description"}`

tried to map "_id" attribute as, to follow proper java bean naming

```
@JsonProperty("_id")
private String id;
```

which results in following error.

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class ] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:917)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:901)
```

if the field name is `private String _id;` json response is de-serialised without any issue. but I don't want to name field starting with '_' in our app.
We are using Jackson-2.7.3 & Spring RestTemplate to make REST calls.

Implementation for consuming the endpoint. Its a simple GET call using Spring RestTemplate.

`HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
return restTemplate.exchange(authorizationProperties.getEndpoint() + "/roles", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,new ParameterizedTypeReference<Auth0Roles>() {});`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean to the controller which consumes request body so that it can map the input Json string to your defined POJO.

Comment: @LHCHIN If I am not wrong the body - Json string is mapped to my defined pojo is happening in return restTemplate.exchange(authorizationProperties.getEndpoint() + "/roles", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,new ParameterizedTypeReference<Auth0Roles>() {}); I am calling the 3rd part end point which returns JSON String with "_id" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to apply the annotation on the accessor methods, not the field itself:

```
   private String id;

   @JsonProperty("_id")
   public String getId() {
      return this.id;
   }
   public void setId(String i) {
      this.id = i;
   }
```

Comment: No doesn't work. I am already using @JsonProperty at field level for other fields which is working. I have noticed problem only with fields starting with '_' underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Its not looking like the problem with JSON. Most probably you are missing the HttpMessageConverter.

Try Adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: already jackson-databind dependency is added "compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'." will upgrade to 2.8.3 & check.

Comment: Try registering the Message converter manually to your rest template

Comment: List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
       
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        messageConverters.add(converter);

Comment: restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);